# 2 Clash of Clans account on the same Game Center account

Tags: game-center, clash-of-clans

At first I started playing clash of clash of clans on my sister's iPad, with her Game Center account. As the months passed by my sister wanted to play on her phone, however her phone is also using the same game center and so whenever my elder sister wants to play Clash of Clans it prompts up on the screen

> Do You want to load "venneline Th8 base"?

which is on my iPad.

Is there a way I can transfer the account on my iPad to a new Game Center account?

Answer (score 1):

**Attach your old village to a new Game Center account:**

Launch Game Center on your old device, create a new free account and login; while logged in, launch the game. If you get the "Welcome back, *yourusername*" message at the top of the screen, your village is now attached to your Game Center account!

**Load your village on the new device:**

Launch Game Center on your new device, and login with the same username and password you used in the old device; while logged in, launch the game, and you will get the following message:

Tap "Okay" to load your old village on the new device.  This will delete the new, unwanted village.

Comment: Attaching my old village to a new game center account will really help me but the load village on the new device part isn't going to help solve my sisters problem as she also plays clash of clans but because my sister is the one that has the new clash of clans base but on the same GC account that I use (which is her GC account) but because I played first it saved my not my sister's is there a way that my sister can save her coc base on her own GC account and not delete it?